# JSF/Rich 2.0 - Call bean method when item selected in rich:select

Tags: events, jsf-2, richfaces

I m trying call method bean when an item is selected in combo (rich: select) as follow:

```
    <rich:select id="combo"
        value="#{bean.code}"
        valueChangeListener="#{bean.productChanged}"
        immediate="true" required="true">
        <a4j:ajax event="change" render="callConflict"
            oncomplete="javascript:showConflict();" />
        <f:selectItems
            value="#{bean.products}" />
        <f:attribute name="attributeName"
            value="#{bean.attribute}" />
    </rich:select>
```

But this code, the method in the bean is only called when the item is changed **AND WHEN THE COMBO LOSES FOCUS**

As should be done to invoke the method on the bean after changing the product without having to wait for combo loses focus?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to solve your problem. One of them, is  removing the focus from your component

```
onlistclick = "x.blur()"
```

or

```
onlistclick = "window.blur()"
```

Yeah, this could work, but I guess it is not the best solution.

Another (better) way is to use:

```
<a4j:ajax event="selectitem" render="xxx"/>
```

Remember that: the event tag may be case senstive. For me, event = "selectItem" does not work (only "selectitem").